# Custom whiteSpace using Haskell Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, whitespace, parsec

I would like to use Parsec's `makeTokenParser` to build my parser, but I want to use my own definition of `whiteSpace`.  Doing the following replaces `whiteSpace` with my definition, but all the `lexeme` parsers still use the old definition (e.g. `P.identifier lexer` will use the old whiteSpace).

```
...
lexer :: P.TokenParser ()
lexer      = l { P.whiteSpace = myWhiteSpace }
   where l = P.makeTokenParser myLanguageDef
...
```

Looking at the code for [`makeTokenParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Token.html#makeTokenParser) I think I understand why it works this way.  I want to know if there are any workarounds to avoid completely duplicating the code for `makeTokenParser`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672142/in-parsec-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-lexeme-from-consuming-newlines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think there is a way. The local definitions used in `makeTokenParser` refer recursively to themselves, and so, as you've noted, `lexeme` uses `whiteSpace` as defined there, rather than the `whiteSpace` record member you replace in your `lexer` object.

The code is taunting because it uses the same names as both local functions in `makeTokenParser` and as record members of the `TokenParser` constructor. They are in fact totally distinct entities.

Comment: Now if only the `TokenParser` were written with type classes, we'd be good to go.

Comment: .. and if it could make monadic parsers (in Parsec 3) rather than be hardwired up to `Identity`.