# In Parsec, is there a way to prevent lexeme from consuming newlines?

Tags: haskell, parsec

All of the parsers in `Text.Parsec.Token` politely use `lexeme` to eat whitespace after a token.  Unfortunately for me, whitespace includes new lines, which I want to use as expression terminators.  Is there a way to convince `lexeme` to leave a new line?

Comment: Have you looked at uu-parsinglib?  It has lexeme and non-lexeme versions of parsers, and built-in error correction too.  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib

Comment: I've solved this before by copying and renaming the Parsec.Token module then changing the definition of `simpleSpace` (near the bottom of the file). This isn't a very modular solution but it does work.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641737/custom-whitespace-using-haskell-parsec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not.  Here is the relevant code.

From [Text.Parsec.Token](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Token.html#GenTokenParser):

```
lexeme p
    = do{ x <- p; whiteSpace; return x  }


--whiteSpace
whiteSpace
    | noLine && noMulti  = skipMany (simpleSpace <?> "")
    | noLine             = skipMany (simpleSpace <|> multiLineComment <?> "")
    | noMulti            = skipMany (simpleSpace <|> oneLineComment <?> "")
    | otherwise          = skipMany (simpleSpace <|> oneLineComment <|> multiLineComment <?> "")
    where
      noLine  = null (commentLine languageDef)
      noMulti = null (commentStart languageDef)
```

One will notice in the where clause of `whitespace` that the only only options looked at deal with comments.  The `lexeme` function uses `whitespace` and it is used liberally in the rest of `parsec.token`.

---

### Update Sept. 28, 2015

The ultimate solution for me was to use a proper lexical analyser ([alex](https://www.haskell.org/alex/)).  Parsec does a very good job as a parsing library and it is a credit to the design that it can be mangled into doing lexical analysis, but for all but small and simple projects it will quickly become unwieldy.  I now use alex to create a linear set of tokens and then Parsec turns them into an AST.

Comment: This is incorrect, `simpleSpace` consumes new line characters.

Answer (score 3):

If newlines are your expression terminators, maybe it would make sense to split the input at each newline and parsing each line on its own.

Comment: newlines are potential terminators, but do not necessarily do so. The same semantics as Haskell itself.

Comment: @John -- are you trying to handle something similar to layout/the offside rule? There's a whole bunch of techniques for that in particular.

Comment: @sclv no, just new lines as expression terminators like one finds in Ruby or JavaScript

Comment: +1, since it's a usable workaround for some languages, even though it doesn't work in the asker's case.

Comment: I tried to parse quite a few format involving recognizing new line with Parsec the solution so far as always been to parse line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not all parsers in `Text.Parsec.Token` use `lexeme`, although all of
them *should*. Worst of all it's not documented which of them consume white
space and which of them do not. Some of the parsers in `Text.Parsec.Token`
do consume white space after lexeme, some of them don't. Some of them
consume leading whitespace as well. You should read existing issues on
GitHub issue tracker if you want to control the situation fully.

In particular:

- `decimal`, `hexadecimal`, and `octal` parsers *do not* consume trailing
  white space, see
  [the source](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/blob/master/Text/Parsec/Token.hs#L568-L570),
  and [this issue](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/issues/43);
- `integer` consumes leading whitespace as well, see
  [this issue](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/issues/39);
- rest of them *probably* consume trailing whitespace and thus newlines,
  this is however difficult to tell for sure because Parsec's code is
  particularly hairy (IMHO) and the project has no test suite (except for 3
  tests which checks that already fixed bugs do not show up again, however
  it's not enough to prevent regressions and every change in source may
  [break your code in next release of Parsec](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/issues/9).)

There are various propositions how to make it configurable (what should be
considered white space), none of them is merged or commented on for some reason.

But the real problem is rather in design of `Text.Parsec.Token`, which locks
user into solutions built by `makeTokenParser`. This design is particularly
non-flexible. There are many cases when only one solution is to copy the
entire module and edit it as needed.

But if you want modern and consistent Parsec there is an option to switch to
[Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) where this (and
many others) problem is non-existent.

---

*Disclosure*: I'm one of the authors of Megaparsec.

Comment: When promoting (or even discussing) your own project/package on SO, you are expected to disclose your connection.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers about it not being possible are correct, I would like to point out that the char parsers are not using a lexeme parser.
I use parsec to analyse some html mustache templates. Whitespaces are important in that analysis. What I did was to simply parse the ">" and "}}" strings with `Text.Parsec.Char.string`.
Since I am interested in whitespaces between tags and not inside them I can still use the reserved operators to parse "<" and "{{" etc., because the lexeme parser only consumes trailing whitespace.